# Why did the population of Descartes, France increase by so much in the 1960's?

Tags: france, demography, 1960s, population

The population of [Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes,_Indre-et-Loire) in central France increased by upwards of 150% from 1962 to 1968 after a general negative trend over the preceding seventy years. Why was this? All I can find is that the town changed its name from "La Haye-Descartes" to simply "Descartes" in 1967. I'd assume it has some relation to the population growth, probably a result of a small town of ~1,700 being flooded with ~2,600 new residents.

Comment: `I'd assume it [the name change] has some relation to the population growth` I certainly wouldn't. I would look for A) how does this population change compare to that of France as a whole B) some new industry being stablished (or an old one flourishing) or C) new infrastructure making it easier to move to/from nearby economic centers.

Comment: @SJuan76 Ok. France's population growth as a whole seems to be unrelated. It's been following a shallow upward slope. Descartes had one spike upwards but has otherwise been going down. I'll look more into your B and C.

Comment: The figures in the table on Wikipedia seem to be the same as the population figures on [this page](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/Descartes%20(Indre-et-Loire)/fr-fr/#cite_note-Cassini-2) which includes a note of the sources used. It looks like the figures up to 1962 were provided by Cassini de l'EHESS (L'Ecole des Hautes Etudes en Science Sociales. From 1968 they're provided by INSEE (the French National Institute of Statistics and Economic Studies). It may simply be that the method used to calculate population is different for the 2 sources.

Comment: Big jump is from 1962-68. I would check out `The Chevènement law tidied up all these practices, abolishing some structures and creating new ones. In addition, it offered central government finance aimed at encouraging further communes to join together in intercommunal structures. Unlike the only partially successful statute enacted in 1966 and enabling urban communes to form urban communities, or the more marked failure of the Marcellin law of 1971, the Chevènement law met with a large measure of success, so that a majority of French communes are now involved in intercommunal structures.`

Comment: %-wise its a big jump. Numerically it was only about 3,000 people.

Comment: @SJuan76 Such big changes within so short a time are usually territorial changes, I would say. Villages usually can't build enough housing this quickly.

Comment: They started thinking more, therefore there were more of them.

Comment: @Graham: Ha Ha! I couldn't figure how to word that properly.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Based on [this page](http://cassini.ehess.fr/cassini/fr/html/fiche.php?select_resultat=16842) from the French [School for Advanced Studies in the Social Sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_for_Advanced_Studies_in_the_Social_Sciences), it appears that the neighbouring [Balsesmes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balesmes) merged into La Haye-Descartes in 1966, before the combined commune was renamed to Descartes the next year.

In 1962, the two communes had remarkably similar population levels of 1,679 and 1,689. With a combined population of 4,267 in 1968, the growth rate was only 26.7%. Still high, mind you, but not the shockingly stratospheric 154% that it initially appears.

Comment: Thought as much, but couldn't track it down. Good work.

Comment: Confirmed by a governmental website: *"01/01/1967 : Haye-Descartes devient Descartes suite à sa fusion avec Balesmes."* https://insee.fr/fr/metadonnees/cog/commune/COM37115-descartes

Comment: One thing that maybe isn't obvious to non-French speakers; "commune" is just their word for "town". It doesn't imply anything special about its political structure outside of that (like it would in English).

Comment: So ..., it was a [Cartesian join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Cartesian_join)?

Comment: @T.E.D : You are wrong here, commune is the most basic political structure in France (most french towns are a commune on their own, but it is not the same). Anyway the fact that the communes of Balsesmes and La Haye Descartes could merge suggests a political structure and not a town. Because, well, they did not move the houses, did they?

Comment: @Steph - I think you misunderstand. [In the US at least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commune#United_States), a "commune" would imply a group of unrelated people living together essentially under a Communist governing system. Likely in the same building or compound of buildings, and pooling all labor, income, and often possessions. Most of them tend to be either religious (cults), or run by (ex?) Hippies. My point being the French word "commune" probably should be *translated* into an appropriate English term.

Comment: @T.E.D. Oh, I see. Well, in the UK, commune is understood like in France and was the official name until the seventies (now those are districts), so I missed the essential difference in American English. Anyway, in the US, it should be translated to *municipality*.

Comment: @Steph - I said "in the US at least" because that's the only English I can really claim expertise with. However, either it isn't *just* US English, or somebody needs to go make some major edits to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commune) and [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commune#Etymology_1) noting the regional differences in meaning. Right now both assert the meaning I gave as **the** primary meaning of the word.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Variants of the word "commune" are used for "municipality" in various countries such as France, Italy, Germany or Sweden, but not in the UK.

Comment: @Steph - Fair enough. The same thing that makes it not "obvious to non-French speakers" likely also makes the issue not obvious to French speakers. :-)